# Post method in Battle.net

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to write python program test the post method. From the picture below, I know

> url=https://www.battlenet.com.cn/login/zh/?ref=https://www.battlenet.com.cn/wow/zh/vault/character/auction/index&app=com-wow

and my account is

```
accountName:<acccount_name>

password:<password>
```

I want to open the web with account name and password, so I write my code

```
import requests

import webbrowser

session = requests.Session()

data={'accountName':'<acccount_name>','password':'<password>'}
r=session.post('https://www.battlenet.com.cn/login/zh/?ref=https://www.battlenet.com.cn/wow/zh/vault/character/auction/index&app=com-wow',data=data)

print(r.cookies.get_dict())

r=session.get('https://www.battlenet.com.cn/login/zh/?ref=https://www.battlenet.com.cn/wow/zh/vault/character/auction/index&app=com-wow')

print(r.text)
```

But from the result, I fail to get the logged web. Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: dang.. you posted all your credentials...

Comment: @B001ᛦ  Could you talk  it detail ? I am a beginner of python, I can't understand you.

Comment: _Could you talk it detail ?_ Yes, you have posted your account and password so everyone can log in and change your password

Comment: I have edited these out but they are still in the history.

Comment: @B001ᛦ  Thanks, it just be a test account, and the password can't be changed without e-mail, don't care about it.

Comment: That's a multi-step login form. The data should be submitted to `https://www.battlenet.com.cn/login/srp?csrfToken=true` as JSON: `json.dumps({"inputs": {"0": {"input_id": "account_name", "value": accountName}}})`, then when you get a valid response (i.e. a user exists) you probably should submit your password in a similar fashion... And there probably are a few more hoops to jump through. This makes your question way too broad to warrant an answer.

Comment: @zwer  Thanks, do you have some recommond reference for me to deal it ? I just be a beginner of python and crawler.